# Dropping values in pandas data frame using operators e.g >,<,= and etc

Tags: pandas

How do i write the python code to drop certain values? E.g. I want to drop an extreme value in the data frame column. I tried to select first before dropping which failed.

data[['Metabolic rate']>2000]
also tried;      data['Metabolic rate'>2000]

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 #your answer
----> 2 data[['Metabolic rate']>2000]

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Try this: data[data['Metabolic rate']>2000]

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Comment: Both attempts should not work as you compare a list `['Metabolic rate']` and then a string `'Metabolic rate'` to 2,000 as error indicates. Instead use Series: `df['Metabolic rate']`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data` is the name of the dataframe:

```
data.drop(data[data['Metabolic rate'] > 2000].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually used a working code for dummies (i am still learning) as below;     
data['Metabolic rate'>2000]      #\n
#\n             data[data['Metabolic rate']>2000]
#\n                            data  #index for >2000 ==39
#\n                                         data_Metab=data.drop(39)